# Is a quotient of a torsion module always a torsion module? Is a direct sum of torsion modules torsion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Is a quotient of a torsion module always a torsion module? Is a direct
>   sum of torsion modules torsion?

I think the second one is yes, but I am not sure about the first one. Can anyone help?

Comment: The first one is true too. $rf(a)=f(ra)$ for homomorphisms of modules.

Comment: [It's true. All of it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip9tIwYd-8M)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $M$ is a torsion module and $A$ is a submodule. Let $f:M\to M/A$ be a surjective homomorphism. Then for every $m'\in M/A$, there exists an $m\in M$ with $f(m)=m'$. If $r\in R$ is such that $rm=0$, then $rf(m)=f(rm)=0$.